# What does the single quote means in C++ Math programming?

Tags: c++

so recently I was reading a book that teach you how to program in C++ and I am at basic math stuff. I'm not a beginner in C++ but I have seen something strange that I can't find on the internet.

It is a math expression: `5*3(6' 4)` and it has a single quote on it. I found didn't know what it was so I checked up on the internet for this and I found only that it is referred as `prime`. But I don't think it solve my problem and I don't know how correct that is.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I want to address all people who commented and answered (and those who will to do the same thing)in this post that I HAVE MADE A BIG MISTAKE. The real math expression was: `5*6(6*4)` but my friend's book(which I got this expression) was not printed well and it looked like the one I have wrote in the past. I'm really really sorry about this....

Comment: Is `5*3(6' 4)` actually in your code?

Comment: Single quotes are used in pairs around character literals.  There is no use as an operator.  Are you sure it wasn't in a comment?

Comment: Well, it says that I need to make a program to solve this math expression.

Comment: @user4581301 haha, the book is old XD sorry

Comment: Is `5*3(6' 4)` the actually expression?  AFAIK that's just nonsense.

Comment: I think this is a math equation (nonsense to me) and not even c++

Comment: Are you sure this is a C++ question? I think it's a mathematical expression

Comment: Guys, I'm saying that I got that from a C++ book. Why would I lie? I just want to know it...

Comment: Maybe a typo in the book.

Comment: Not every expression in a C++ book is actual C++ code. It could be a mathematical term or pseudo code.

Comment: Could we get what book and what part of it you are referring to?  Sometimes context can mean everything.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica please believe me, I went tooo close with the book to clarify it. I also were doubt of that.

Comment: Wolfram alpha says the result is 95 feet

Comment: I don't think this book is in English version

Comment: "_Well, it says that I need to make a program to solve this math expression._" You should ask on a math board.

Comment: Probably could be but we are speaking here for C++ and not actual math xD

Comment: Its a C++ program, I'm not seeking or caring about to solve that

Comment: Is it _a math expression_ or _a C++ program_? Please decide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++14 and up allows single quote `'` inside [integer literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal) to allow for grouping digits. Thanks to this, `123'456'789` can be used as more readable equivalent to `123456789`.

Depending on a country, it may be also used in mathematical (outside of C++) expressions, although Polish people would rather use `123 456 789` and UK people would use a comma AFAIK - `123,456,789`. None of these is valid in C++ (or it would yield results far from expected), but it would be reasonable in mathematical text/formula.

Nevertheless, your example still wouldn't compile. There is no operator between `3` and opening bracket `(`.

Comment: Yeah that's right. I tried to compile and it fired up me an error. My book is kind of old and by the time they were writing it it must have been C++14. Thanks for the answer.